# Cannot see any git branches

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio, branch

I cloned a repo from Github. It was an eclipse Android project. I then imported it into Android Studio and have now got it up and running. I ran "git init" and am now trying to create a branch to work off of.

when I run git branch I get nothing. Terminal returns nothing and just goes to the next line. i have tried running git branch -a and git branch --list and still am getting nothing. There is no master branch showing or any branch for that matter.

I ran git checkout -b  and it said the branch was created. But when I run git branch I still get nothing returned. I then tried to run git checkout master and received:

```
git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I am not sure why this is happening and think it has something to do with the weird initial setup. (clone repo, then import into android studio, then run git init)

Comment: Did you cd into the directory after running clone?

Comment: What do you mean by "importing it into Android Studio"? Did you just check out a working copy of the project, without carrying the repo's history along with it, somehow? My guess is that you ran `git init` in a folder that wasn't a Git repository in the first place. Running `git branch` in such a brand new repository will output nothing... Inspect the `.git/objectssubdirectory` in your repo. Is it empty?

Comment: @Jubobs There is a pack and info directory inside the objects subdirectory. They are both empty.

Comment: @Humdinger Yes I did

Comment: @user3520299 It means that the folder in which you ran `git init` is not where your clone resides. What do you mean by "import into Android Studio"? What did you do for that?

Comment: I cloned the file down locally from the command line. I then imported the project into Android Studio, so that Android Studio would do all the setup work for the switch from Eclipse. It looks like Android Studio creates a copy to do this and puts this into a different directory which does not have git set up. I am trying to figure out now how to get git working properly in this new directory and git init doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Looks like when Android Studio copies the project and migrates it from Eclipse to AS setup, I lose the git history of the project. Once I make my initial commit I think the master branch will set up.

Comment: I'm not sure how importing a project into Android Studio works, but if you want the Git repository to follow, you should make sure that a copy of the `.git` subdirectory (from the clone) is in your Android-Studio project directory.

Comment: @Jubobs copying that .git subdirectory fixed the problem and I now have all the history of the repo. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @user3520299 Great news. Should I write an actual answer below?

Comment: Yea I think that would be great, I will upvote it to make sure others see it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`git init` is for initializing a new git repository.  Since you cloned from an existing repository on Github, there is no need to initialize a new one.

In general, if you `git init` to initialize a new repo, and then immediately invoke `git branch` without making any commits or creating any branches, then the behavior you experienced is expected:  `git branch` will return nothing.  Only after your initial commit (or you explicitly create a branch) will you see any branches listed.

In particular if you ran your `git init` and `git clone` in the same directory where you ran `git clone` to begin with, then you will not see any branches.  If you change directory into the subdirectory that was created when you cloned, then `git branch` will probably list `master` for you (and `git remote show origin` will show you the remote branches).